# Android: ProductFlavors Manifest and Java Class

Tags: manifest

I am working with ProductFlavors and my case is as follows:
I will have two versions (Free and Paid), the version of Paga will have more permissions as "READ_CALL_LOG", "READ_SMS", "PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" among others, I have configure the gladle of the following form:

```html
flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
        basic {
            applicationId "com.dlt.miapp.basic"
            resValue 'string', 'google_maps_key', 'API_KEY
            sourceSets {
                main {
                    manifest.srcFile "src/basic/AndroidManifest.xml"
                }
            }
        }
        full {
            applicationId "com.dlt.miapp.full"
            resValue 'string', 'google_maps_key', 'API_KEY'
            sourceSets {
                main {
                    manifest.srcFile "src/full/AndroidManifest.xml"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I have the structure of the project.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJ9PT.jpg

Copy all the files from the "layout" folder in each flavor, should I also copy the entire java directory in each one?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI32I.jpg

For now I have the following:

This is the content of the Manifest file:

```html
    <!-- Permisions Basic -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

    <!-- Permission Paid -->
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />-->
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />-->
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />-->
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />-->
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />-->
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />-->
```

I have read this and month I am guiding:

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants?fbclid=IwAR0UiYkRvhQLILmirH6odk1YBYls7eJ3rh9K7nNR9UGtHQgsUYw-12j6ZUI#configure-sourcesets

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html?fbclid=IwAR3Zqn2-sfbU0dVLecBJImp_rZo9wpNL0rsa13iQD7CoR3Hqcuw9lncqxwQ

Regards